# What affects geofence triggering? How to troubleshoot?

Tags: geofencing

I am getting very inconsistent plot results with different devices. Here are some of the issues I have noticed:
The same fences and triggers are deployed to both devices, but:
1) One device is only triggering the exit event on a particular fence, the other doesn't fire the exit event at all.
2) Both devices are not firing the geofence enter or exit events for a series of geofences I have created. I have tried going into the fence and waiting to see if the enter ever fires and does not.

I am retrieving the list of active triggers using the plugin to ensure the triggers are registered with the device.

What can affect geofence triggering behaviour and how do you troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

Which devices are you testing with? And are you testing with the Plot Projects demo app or your own app with Plot integrated?

Whether a geofences triggers or not is dependent on a number of things, such as accuracy of the location update. You can troubleshoot the behaviour of our plugin by checking the debug log. How you can use this is explained in this blog post: https://www.plotprojects.com/how-to-test-plot-integration-with-debug-log/

In case you are using Titanium, we expose a `mailDebugLog()` method for that framework, this is explained in the documentation here: https://github.com/Plotprojects/plot-titanium-module#function-reference